# I am new in react i want to convert normal javascript code to the react i don't know how to do that

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

this is my react java script where i want to insert the normal js code.
I have tried by using the {} brackets but that won't run.

```
import './App.css';


function App() {
  


  return (
    
    <>
    <div className="container"></div><div className="box">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="form-wrapper sign-in">
          <form action="">
            <h2 className="he">Login</h2>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input className="ip1" type="text" required/>
                <label for="">Username</label>
                <i></i>
              </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input type="password" required/>
                <label for="">Password</label>
                <i></i>
              </div>
  
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <div className="signUp-link">
              <p className="p1">Don't have an account? <a href="#" className="signUpBtn-link">Sign Up</a></p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div className="form-wrapper sign-up">
          <form action="">
            <h2 className="he2">Sign Up</h2>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input type="text" required/>
                <label for="">Username</label>
                <i></i>
              </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input type="text" required/>
                <label for="">Email</label>
                <i></i>
           
            <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            <div className="signUp-link">
              <p>Already have an account? <a href="#" className="signInBtn-link">Sign In</a></p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></>
 );
}
export default App;
```

This is the code that i wanto to merge.
I Want to merge the following code in the above code. I have a normal javaScript code but i don't know how to write it in the React

```
const signInBtnLink = document.querySelector('.signInBtn-link');
const signUpBtnLink = document.querySelector('.signUpBtn-link');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

signUpBtnLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    wrapper.classList.toggle('active');
});

signInBtnLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    wrapper.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Comment: Here is the official tutorial https://beta.reactjs.org/learn

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of react js !!, start your leanings here
[react js](https://www.w3schools.com/REACT/DEFAULT.ASP)

Comment: People used to love to find any way to help here, lately, it's getting filled with people who forgot that they were beginners and made judgments.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you put your js codes to a file for example : public/assets/js/yourfile.js
and import it like this:

```
 import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useExternalScript = (url) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [url]); // Re-run this hook if the url changes
};

// Usage inside a component
function MyComponent() {
  useExternalScript('public/assets/js/yourfile.js');

  // Component logic
}
```

This is a safe way to run external JS in React without having DOM issues